# Create bins with 1 percentage increments?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with column activity_percentage of a customer. This range is from 0-100%. Now, I want to create bin for each percentage but my current approach will require me to manually create 100 bins which is probably not the best way. How can I achieve this in a more programmatic way?

```
def conditions(x):
    if   x >=0 and  x<=0.01:   return "0-1%"
    elif x >0.01 and x<=0.02:   return "1-2%"
    elif x >0.02 and x<=0.03:   return "2-3%"
    ....                        return 99-100%
    else:
      return "error"
```

Comment: Can you share a sample of `activity_percentage` column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will allow you to choose the increments that you want to look at. First, find the remainder of your `value` * 100 divided by the `increment`, then multiply that number by the `increment` to get the bottom range of your increments. If the bottom range is less than 100, print the bottom range to the bottom range plus your `increment`. Account for if the bottom range is 100 (because you don't want to put that in e.g. 100-107%), then return an "Error" message if the value would be placed in a range above 100%.

```
def conditions(value, increment):
    bottomRange = value*100 // increment * increment
    if value > 1:
        return("Error")    
    elif (bottomRange + increment) <= 100:
        return f"{bottomRange} - {bottomRange+increment}%"
    elif (bottomRange + increment) > 100 or value == 1:
        return f"{bottomRange} - 100%"      

conditions(0.62, 10) # output: '60.0 - 70.0%'

conditions(0.05, 3) # output: '3.0 - 6.0%'

conditions(0.98, 7) # output: '98.0 - 100%'
```

Comment: How would this change if I wanted to have 5% increments instead of 1%?

Comment: @titutubs check the edit, you just change the increments in the range, `>=` to  `>` and the amount you subtract from `y`

Comment: How does that `for` loop differ from just directly computing `y=math.floor(x*100)`? (Aside from taking up to 100 times as many cycles.)

Comment: @rici corrected to not need a loop nor another module, thank you

Comment: @titutubs , check the edit for a better solution, now you can choose what your increment is without needing to change the function and without the need of looping